# Users created, with different parameters in a single result, grouped by week

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres, I am trying to find each weeks' statistics broken down for users.  Not only would I want to know the number of users created, I would want to know the number of users created that didn't have a last name, or an email address.

The query below works just fine for the total number of users, but how would I get other columns of data to have a more limited set?  Aside from doing multiple selects and assignments is there anything else that postgres has handy that I am not seeing?:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', users.created_at) AS "Week" , count(*) AS "No. of created users"
FROM users
WHERE users.created_at > now() - interval '12 months' 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Here is what I am looking for the result set to look like:

```
| Week                | No. Created Users | Created without email | Created without last name |

| 2016-01-04 | 200               | 85                    | 12                        |

| 2016-01-11 | 400               | 93                    | 29                        |

| 2016-01-18 | 150               | 84                    | 12                        |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find COUNT on a CASE like so:

```
SELECT 
    date_trunc('week', users.created_at) AS "Week",
    count(*) AS "No. of created users",
    count(case when email_id is null then 1 end) "Without email",
    count(case when lastname is null then 1 end) "Without lastname"
FROM users
WHERE users.created_at > now() - interval '12 months' 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I wasn't thinking about!